# How to proof information inequality with uncertainty entropy?

Tags: probability, random-variables

The uncertainty (= entropy) of a discrete random variable X in [bit] is defined by
H(X) = E {−ld(pX(X))} = −
P
x∈supp(pX )
pX(x)ld(pX(x))

Problem
Using the information inequality which says that ld(x) ≤ (x − 1)ld(e) with equality
if and only if x = 1, show that 0 ≤ H(X) ≤ ld(L) for X ∈ {x1, . . . , xL} and
equality if and only if X is uniformly distributed with P(X = xi) = 1/L for all i.

Can somebody help me with this problem?

Comment: This question is hard to understand because your notation is odd-looking.  What, for instance, is "ld"? And shouldn't the big P at the end of your first sentence be a summation sign?

Comment: Id means log2 and the big P is probability like, for example, P(X=xi).